# Distributed Dask CPP workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

DASK has a very powerful distributed api. As far as I can understand it can only support though native python code and modules.

Does anyone know if distributed DASK can support c++ workers?
I could not find anything in the docs.

Would there be any other approach apart from adding python bindings to cpp code to use that functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, if you wanted to call into C++ code using Dask, you would do it by calling from python, which usually means writing some form of binding layer to make the calling convenient. If there is also a C API, you could use `ctypes` or `cffi`.

In theory, the scheduler is agnostic of the language of the client and workers, so long as they agree with each other, but no one has implemented a C++ client/worker. This has been done, at leats a POC, for Julia.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I was just exploring the option of having a c++ worker for computational efficiency and speed. What do you mean the scheduler is agnostic? I read already the open [issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/586) in your git but there aren't much details there. Do you mean the add_plugin functionality of the scheduler?

Comment: No, I mean that a python (or cython, if someone does that) scheduler could in theory interact with client/workers of other languages.